Laravel routes with multiple segments causes assets to be not found
If i have more than one segment on my routes it messes up my assets path
when i visit url('/blogadmin') my assets are found on href="admin/css/simplebar.css"
But when i visit url('/blogs/1/edit') my assets url becomes blogs/1/admin/css/simplebar.css and i cant load on my blade template. Any help

It sounds like you're having absolute/vs relative path issues. Put'/' in front of your asset links.

I have tried all that with '/' or './' thingy none of that works

Perhaps you should share the actual code

I found that i can use utility called asset to get rid of complications href={{asset("img/smile-logo-small.png")}}
